# how to give border for tablerow in tablelayout in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

I need to show border around `TableRow` in `TableLayout`.

How would i do that???

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I give one idea -> Create one xml file using **shape** tag

**like this**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
  <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#515151"/>
  <corners android:radius="3dp" />
  <padding android:left="10dp" android:top="5dp"
    android:right="10dp" android:bottom="5dp" />
</shape>
```

set this xml file in **android:background="@drawable/xmlFilename"** of your table layout

it gives the border around your tablelayout

Comment: as i wasn't able to add the background through xml file but was able to add this feature through .java file tablelayout.setBackgroundResource(R.layout.shape);

Comment: android:background="R.layout.xmlFilename" is the wrong way to do this. Use `android:background="@drawable/filename_of_xml"` instead.