# How to create a table exactly as we create in html that is table with borders?

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I am trying to create a table in android with borders but not able to achieve the task.

[image]

I am working with target SDK version 23.

Following is the code for my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/enquiryLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:shrinkColumns="*"
    android:stretchColumns="*">

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_span="4"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Table 2"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="A"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="B"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="C"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="D"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="E"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="F"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="G"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="H"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="I"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="J"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="K"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="L"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**The problem is I am not able to display the borders in the table otherwise the table is created properly.**
Please guide me to accomplish the task shown in the figure.

Comment: The problem is I am not able to display the borders in the table otherwise the table is created properly.

Comment: You can set background to table layout, see this answer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35762006/android-lolipop-how-to-have-edittext-with-border/35762152#35762152

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5562193/4350275

Comment: No @ELITE its for giving the outline to the view as i tried to do as in the question suggested by you its creating boxes and not creating borders.

Comment: The example suggested by you is to give a table border but what about the rows and columns of the table @PrerakSola?

Comment: @SwapnilLanjewar you can set this border to `TableLayout` and to all `TableRow` elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of searching and digging I made it working. Thank you guys for the support!!!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/enquiryLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:shrinkColumns="*"
    android:stretchColumns="*">

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_span="4"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Table 2"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="0.5dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="A"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="0.5dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="B"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="0.5dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="C"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="0.5dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="D"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="0.5dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="E"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="0.5dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="F"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="0.5dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="G"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="0.5dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="H"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="0.5dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="I"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="0.5dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="J"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="0.5dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="K"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="0.5dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="L"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </TableRow>
 </TableLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create two xmls. One for the row & table and the other for columns.

**table_row.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
    <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#000000"/>
</shape>
```

**table.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#515151"/>
    <corners android:radius="3dp" />
</shape>
```

Assign `table.xml` as background to `TableLayout` and `TableRow` tags. And for assign `table_row.xml` as background to your `TextView` tags.

Example:

```
<TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:shrinkColumns="*"
        android:stretchColumns="*"
        android:background="@drawable/table">

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/table"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_span="4"
            android:background="@drawable/table_row"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Table 2"

            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```