# Android TabLayout With Border On Top

Tags: android, tabs

I read documentation about `TabLayout` for add property to make border on top of `TabLayout` but I didn't find it anywhere in documentation.

So I want some trick to make `TabLayout` have border on top (or maybe at bottom).

Comment: see this, is a good solution:<br />
http://stackoverflow.com/a/5562193/4102927

Comment: so I must wrap tablayout with some view?

Answer (score 3):

Solved with this drawable xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#FFDDDDDD" />
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:top="1dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />
            <solid android:color="#00000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

and set into tablayout attribute/property:

```
android:background="@drawable/drawableName"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom ViewPager Strip.

> Try this: https://github.com/ogaclejapan/SmartTabLayout

Answer (score 1):

you have to create a drawable, then call in this way

```
android:background="@drawable/yourShapeHere"
```

the drawable is looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
      <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#515151"/>
      <corners android:radius="3dp" />
      <padding android:left="10dp" android:top="5dp" />
  </shape>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, you give me some idea. I was modified your code.