# .net maui bottom (navigation) Tab Bar top(border) line

Tags: .net, maui

How can I get a horizontal line above tab bar on Android and IOS?
Here is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60977945/xamarin-tab-bar-topborder-line) on stack overflow for xamarin forms. I tried to use the new handler. But I don't know if I am doing it right.

```
Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.TabbedViewHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping(nameof(IView.Background), (handler, view) =>
        {
           if (view is BottomNavigationView )
            {
#if __ANDROID__

                Android.Graphics.Drawables.ShapeDrawable line = new()
                {
                    Alpha = 255
                };

                line.Paint.Color = Colors.Black.ToAndroid();
                line.Paint.SetStyle(Android.Graphics.Paint.Style.Fill);
                var layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(new Drawable[] { line });
                layerDrawable.SetLayerInset(0, 0, 0, 0, int.Parse((view.Height - 4).ToString()));
                (handler.PlatformView as global::Android.Views.View).SetBackground(layerDrawable);

                
#endif
            }
        });
```

Comment: did you manage to get this working on maui?

Answer (score 1):

On iOS the line is always there. I found a workaround which works for my. The trick is using a brush to draw the BarBackground:

```
<TabbedPage.BarBackground>
<OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Brush">
    <On Platform="Android">
        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0"
                             EndPoint="0,1">
            <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource SeparatorColor}"
                          Offset="0.0" />
            <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource SeparatorColor}"
                          Offset="0.01" />
            <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource BackgroundColor}"
                          Offset="0.01" />
            <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource BackgroundColor}"
                          Offset="1.0" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </On>
    <On Platform="iOS">
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource BackgroundColor}" />
    </On>
</OnPlatform>
</TabbedPage.BarBackground>
```

Answer (score 0):

The process for creating a cross-platform .NET MAUI custom control, whose platform implementations are provided by `handlers`, is as follows:

1. Create a class for the cross-platform control, which provides the
   control's public API. For more information, [see this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/create#create-the-cross-platform-control).
2. Create any required additional cross-platform types.
3. Create a partial handler class. For more information, see [Create the
   handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/create#create-the-handler).
4. In the handler class, create a PropertyMapper dictionary, which
   defines the Actions to take when cross-platform property changes
   occur. For more information, see [Create the property mapper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/create#create-the-property-mapper).
5. Optionally, in your handler class, create a CommandMapper
   dictionary, which defines the Actions to take when the
   cross-platform control sends instructions to the native views that
   implement the cross-platform control. For more information, see
   [Create the command mapper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/create#create-the-command-mapper).
6. Create partial handler classes for each platform that create the
   native views that implement the cross-platform control. For more
   information, see [Create the platform controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/create#create-the-platform-controls).
7. Register the handler using the ConfigureMauiHandlers and AddHandler
   methods in your app's MauiProgram class. For more information, see
   Register the handler.

```
      .ConfigureMauiHandlers(handlers =>
            {
                handlers.AddHandler(typeof(CustomControl), typeof(CustomControlHandler));
            });
```

Reference link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/

Sample repo:https://github.com/dotnet/maui-samples/tree/main/6.0/UserInterface/Handlers/CreateHandlerDemo

Comment: Hi Alexander,
Thank you for the complete example and explanation. But It looks a bit too much for just a horizontal or shadow on a bottom navigation bar. In xamarin forms the amount of code was basically a custom renderer with a function and it worked. Can you show me how to do this in .net maui?

Comment: Similarly, we use [handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/) in Maui. If you want to use Custom Renderer in MAUI, you can refer to [this thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1005371/how-yo-create-custom-shell-renderer-in-microsoft-m.html).

Comment: Hi sorry for my late reply, But do you have example code for me I can use? I read the handlers section and it looks to complicated. I would appreciate sample code just for the top border. Thanks.